# Include javascript code in wp_head only on woocommerce cart page and get cart sub-total and currency

Tags: woocommerce

On the woocommerce cart page I need to include an event snippet (in `wp_head`) and pass it both the value of the cart and the selected currency. Here is the code I have so far:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'cart_page_tracking_codes');
function cart_page_tracking_codes() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('is_cart') ) return;
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

    ?>
    <script>
        pintrk('track', 'addtocart', {
        value: <?php echo $cart_total; ?>,
        // order_quantity: 1,
        currency: 'USD'
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I am stuck on getting the currency. Note the store offers both USD and CAD.
`get_currency()` is related to an existing Woocommerce Order.

Comment: What format should value be in? 5.99? $5.99? 599? WooCommerce only supports a single currency by default so you'd need to provide more details on how you're adding support for additional currencies.

Comment: I am using the PRO version of this plugin: https://www.pricebasedcountry.com/
I have submitted a support ticket. 
`5.99` is the format I would need.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you're looking for is `is_cart()` rather than `is_wc_endpoint_url()`.

Based on the follow-up comment, you also need the unformatted price. `get_cart_total()` will format for display (adding currency symbol, etc) by default. If you use `get_total()` and pass in a context other than view however, it'll return the unformatted value.

WooCommerce doesn't support multiple currencies by default so the currency aspect of it will depend on the plugin you're using. I've written the answer using WooCommerce's base currency. You'll need to speak with the plugin's support team to determine how to access the customer's selected currency.

```
function wpse_insert_cart_tracking_script() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
        return;
    } ?>

    <script>
        pintrk('track', 'addtocart', {
            value: <?php echo WC()->cart->get_total( 'raw' ); ?>,
            currency: '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>'
        });
    </script>

    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_insert_cart_tracking_script' );
```